# SAPUI5: How to use DateTimepicker with Timestamp17 UTC model value

Tags: datetime, model-view-controller, sapui5

I am using in my database for Date and Time information the following format "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"
20211119143315000 and UTC. This corresponds to 19th November 2021 14:33:15 and 0 milliseconds in GMT+0.
The timezone is always UTC in the database. If my localtime in GMT 1 that example will be displayed as 19th November 2021 15:33:15 local time.
I use a DateTimePicker in my dialog and succeeded to display the correct local time with the following configuration in the XML View:

```
<DateTimePicker id="dp_lastUsedDate" valueFormat ="yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS Z" value="{path:'mdlPRTData>mp_last_used_date'}"/>
```

My issue is the format of the model value after I pick a date in the dialog. After I pick a date, the format of the value in the model is changed:
My actual local time is GMT+1

- Original model value: 20211119143315000
- Displayed value: 19.11.2021 15:33:15
- Picked value: 19.11.2021 16:33:15
- new model value: **20211119163315000 +0100**
- what I would expect: 20211119153315000

I could not find a solution (without making an individual change and formatter functions) for this requirement.´
Any tipps?

Comment: Try changing your value property to the following: `<DateTimePicker value="{ path: 'mdlPRTData>mp_last_used_date', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: {  UTC: true } }" />`

Comment: Thank for the answer: I get now the following error:  

Uncaught TypeError: j.getTime is not a function
    at D.format (DateFormat-dbg.js:1502)
    at constructor.a.formatValue (Date-dbg.js:79)
    at f.P._rawToExternal (PropertyBinding-dbg.js:129)
    at f.P._getBoundValue (PropertyBinding-dbg.js:83)
    at f.P.getExternalValue (PropertyBinding-dbg.js:196)
    at ManagedObject-dbg.js:3576
    at SyncPromise-dbg.js:308
    at c (SyncPromise-dbg.js:60)
    at new S (SyncPromise-dbg.js:224)
    at S.then (SyncPromise-dbg.js:307)

Comment: The new Element looks like this:   `<DateTimePicker id="dp_lastUsedDate" valueFormat ="yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS Z" value="{ path: 'mdlPRTData>mp_last_used_date', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: {  UTC: true } }" change=".EventHandler.onDateChanged"  enabled="{path:'mdlEdit>/editable'}"/> `

Comment: Can you remove the property valueFormat?

Comment: Same error. I guess the problem is, that my format is not a standard Datetime format. I do not think that SAPUI5 can interprete my format without knowing the valueFormat